# Get Path of Image in PHP/SQLite

Tags: php, html, sql, sqlite

I am attempting to get the path of an image in an SQLite database. This is my code:

```
<img src="<?php
    $database = new PDO("sqlite:database.sqlite");
    $database->query("SELECT path FROM images WHERE receiverId = '$_COOKIE['session']'");
?>" />
```

The table is images and the id of the user is stored in the cookie.

An image has 3 entries: `id`, `senderId` and `receiverId`. If the `receiverId` is the same as the cookie id (the user id), the image should be displayed. However, this code is not working. How can I fix it/recode it?

Comment: did you make sure receiverId and $_COOKIE['session'] is giving the same result? and that is not y it is not working?

Comment: I did. I think the main question I have is, is the return of the query a string that can be used as the src?

Comment: why don't you do that outside src? and assign the value to a variable and echo the result in src?

Comment: more important question why there is no `echo` used here

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/)

Comment: Like this? <?php
                    $database = new PDO('sqlite:database.sqlite');
                    $r = $database -> query('SELECT path FROM images WHERE receiverId = \"$_COOKIE["session"]\" ');
?>
                    <img src="<?php echo '$r'; ?>" />

Comment: yes, I think this is step in right direction

Comment: In this case, is $r a string?

Comment: after you execute fetch, $r['path'] would be, but you say there are only 3 entries in the table ;) http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the results of the query:

```
<?php

  $database = new PDO('sqlite:database.sqlite');
  $r = $database->query('SELECT path FROM images WHERE receiverId = ' . $database->quote($_COOKIE["session"]));
  $v = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<img src='<?= $v["path"] ?>'>
```

---

To make finding your problem easier, add a few debug statements:

```
// ... create $database
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// ... run the query (creating $r)
var_dump($r);

// ... fetch the results
var_dump($v);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. It doesn't even show the missing image logo.

Comment: Is the value of `$r` false? If so, does PDO give you an error message?

Comment: Just to be sure, the resulting tag is `<img src=''>`, correct?

Comment: You said the images have 3 entries each (`id`, `senderId` and `receiverId`). Did you add the `path` column to the database?

Comment: Sorry, the id entry should be "path."

Comment: I've updated the answer with some things you should try to make this easier