# Getting Image Path from SQLite Database

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I have a path to an image stored in a  SQLite table called `images` under column `path`. I am trying to take that path and use it as the `src` attribute for an HTML image. So far, it's not working. How do I convert the result of a query to a string the `src` can use?

```php
<img src="<?php
  $database = new PDO("sqlite:database.sqlite");
  $database->query("SELECT path FROM images WHERE receiverId = '$_COOKIE['session']'");
?>" />
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262804/get-path-of-image-in-php-sqlite

Comment: can you post the code that you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the image data into base64 and stick it in an  tag. Currently, you are trying to write text outside of the image data, and the internet browser thinks your text is part of the image and thus throws an error.

Try something like this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['imageContent'] ) . '" />';
echo 'Hello world.';
```

Comment: Just so you know, I am not receiving any errors. The image just doesn't display. But I will try this.